# Exploring how densities can be approximated by histograms in R

Tags: mathematics, r

```
# Task 1: Generate 10000 random numbers from the exponential distribution with mean 2

# Set the parameters for the exponential distribution
mean_exp <- 2
n <- 10000

# Generate 10000 random numbers from the exponential distribution with mean 2
random_exp <- rexp(n, rate = 1/mean_exp)

# Plot a histogram of these data using the hist function, with 40 bins and relative frequencies
hist_exp <- hist(random_exp, breaks = 40, freq = FALSE,
                 main = "Task 1: Histogram of Exponential Distribution",
                 xlab = "Value", ylab = "Density",
                 col = "lightblue", border = "black")

# Improve the appearance of the plot
box(bty = "L") # Add a box around the plot
axis(1, col.axis = "blue") # Color the x-axis labels blue
axis(2, col.axis = "blue") # Color the y-axis labels blue
title(col.main = "darkblue") # Color the title dark blue

# Plot the density of the exponential distribution in the same plot
curve(dexp(x, rate = 1/mean_exp), col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)

# Add a legend to the plot
legend("topright", legend = c("Histogram", "Density"),
       col = c("lightblue", "red"), lty = c(0, 1), lwd = c(2.5, 2), pch = c(15, -1))



# Task 2: Compare histograms with different numbers of bins

# Set the parameters for the exponential distribution (if not defined earlier)
mean_exp <- 2
n <- 10000

# Generate 10000 random numbers from the exponential distribution with mean 2 (if not generated earlier)
random_exp <- rexp(n, rate = 1/mean_exp)

# Optimal number of bins using the square root rule
optimal_bins <- round(sqrt(n))

# Much lower number of bins
lower_bins <- 10

# Much higher number of bins
higher_bins <- 200

# Create a 3x1 plot layout
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))

# Plot the histogram with optimal number of bins
hist(random_exp, breaks = optimal_bins, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 2: Histogram with Optimal Bins",
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dexp(x, rate = 1/mean_exp), col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE, n = 1000)
legend("topright", legend = c("Histogram (Exponential, mean=2)", "Density"), col = c("lightblue", "red"), lty = c(0, 1), lwd = c(2.5, 2), pch = c(15, NA))

# Plot the histogram with much lower number of bins
hist(random_exp, breaks = lower_bins, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 2: Histogram with Lower Number of Bins",
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dexp(x, rate = 1/mean_exp), col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE, n = 1000)
legend("topright", legend = c("Histogram (Exponential, mean=2)", "Density"), col = c("lightblue", "red"), lty = c(0, 1), lwd = c(2.5, 2), pch = c(15, NA))

# Plot the histogram with much higher number of bins
hist(random_exp, breaks = higher_bins, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 2: Histogram with Higher Number of Bins",
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dexp(x, rate = 1/mean_exp), col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE, n = 1000)
legend("topright", legend = c("Histogram (Exponential, mean=2)", "Density"), col = c("lightblue", "red"), lty = c(0, 1), lwd = c(2.5, 2), pch = c(15, NA))

# Reset the plot layout
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))


# Task 3: Approximate the density of the standard normal distribution

# Generate random samples from the standard normal distribution
n1 <- 1000
n2 <- 10000
n3 <- 100000

random_norm1 <- rnorm(n1)
random_norm2 <- rnorm(n2)
random_norm3 <- rnorm(n3)

# Set the number of bins for each histogram
bins1 <- round(sqrt(n1))
bins2 <- round(sqrt(n2))
bins3 <- round(sqrt(n3))

# Create a 3x1 plot layout
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))

# Plot the histogram for n1 samples
hist(random_norm1, breaks = bins1, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 3: Approximation with 1,000 Samples",
     xlab = "Standard Normal Value", ylab = "Probability Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dnorm(x), from = min(random_norm1), to = max(random_norm1), n = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
legend("topright", legend = c("Standard Normal Distribution", "Histogram"),
       col = c("red", "lightblue"), lwd = c(2, 2), bty = "n")

# Plot the histogram for n2 samples
hist(random_norm2, breaks = bins2, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 3: Approximation with 10,000 Samples",
     xlab = "Standard Normal Value", ylab = "Probability Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dnorm(x), from = min(random_norm2), to = max(random_norm2), n = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
legend("topright", legend = c("Standard Normal Distribution", "Histogram"),
       col = c("red", "lightblue"), lwd = c(2, 2), bty = "n")

# Plot the histogram for n3 samples
hist(random_norm3, breaks = bins3, freq = FALSE,
     main = "Task 3: Approximation with 100,000 Samples",
     xlab = "Standard Normal Value", ylab = "Probability Density",
     col = "lightblue", border = "black")
curve(dnorm(x), from = min(random_norm3), to = max(random_norm3), n = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
legend("topright", legend = c("Standard Normal Distribution", "Histogram"),
       col = c("red", "lightblue"), lwd = c(2, 2), bty = "n")

# Reset the plot layout
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))


# Task 4
# Load the required library
if (!requireNamespace("EnvStats", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("EnvStats")
}

library(EnvStats)

# Set the parameters for the Pareto distribution
xm <- 1
alpha <- 1

# Generate 10000 random data from the Pareto distribution
random_data <- rpareto(10000, location = xm, shape = alpha)

# Plot the histogram
hist(random_data, main = "Task 4: Histogram of Random Data from Pareto Distribution",
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "Frequency", breaks = 100, col = "skyblue", border = "black")

# Add legends
legend("topright", c("Pareto Distribution", 
                     paste("Location (xm):", xm), 
                     paste("Shape (alpha):", alpha), 
                     "Sample Size: 10000"),
       col = c("skyblue", NA, NA, NA), pch = c(15, NA, NA, NA), bty = "n", pt.cex = 1.5, cex = 0.8, text.font = 4)


# Task 5
# Load the required library
if (!requireNamespace("EnvStats", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("EnvStats")
}

library(EnvStats)

# Set the location parameter for the Pareto distribution
xm <- 1

# Create a vector of shape parameter values to investigate
alpha_values <- seq(0.5, 3, by = 0.5)

# Generate histograms for different shape parameter values
par(mfrow = c(2, 3), mar = c(4, 4, 2, 1))
for (alpha in alpha_values) {
  random_data <- rpareto(10000, location = xm, shape = alpha)
  hist(random_data, main = paste("Task 5: Histogram of Pareto (1,", alpha, ")"),
       xlab = "Value", ylab = "Frequency", breaks = 100, col = "skyblue", border = "black",
       xlim = c(0, 10))
}



# Task 6
# Load the required library
if (!requireNamespace("EnvStats", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("EnvStats")
}

library(EnvStats)

# Set the parameters for the Pareto distribution
xm <- 1
alpha <- 1

# Generate 10000 random data from the Pareto distribution
random_data <- rpareto(10000, location = xm, shape = alpha)

# Set the threshold for trimming the data
c <- 10

# Trim the data by removing values greater than or equal to c
trimmed_data <- random_data[random_data < c]

# Plot the histogram of the trimmed data
hist(trimmed_data, main = "Task 6: Histogram of Trimmed Data from Pareto Distribution",
     xlab = "Value", ylab = "Frequency", breaks = 50, col = "skyblue", border = "black")

# Add legends
legend("topright", c("Pareto Distribution (Trimmed)", 
                     paste("Location (xm):", xm), 
                     paste("Shape (alpha):", alpha), 
                     "Sample Size: 10000",
                     paste("Threshold (c):", c)),
       col = c("skyblue", NA, NA, NA, NA), pch = c(15, NA, NA, NA, NA), bty = "n", pt.cex = 1.5, cex = 0.8, text.font = 4)
```

All the code above is an answer to each task below. I am confident that I have answered each task correctly. I just need some clarity. Also any ideas that can further advance my outputs etc.

[image]